# Cannot Bake Bone Animation

Tags: animation, bones, baking

So I have this bone animation with all the constraints, and I want to bake all the bones so that I can get rid of all the unnecessarry bones and keep my armature clean. Here is what I did: in Pose Mode, I chose all the bones and went pose -> animation -> bake action, as shown here: [image: bake]

And when I clicked OK, Blender said: nothing to bake[image: nothing to bake]

I tried to bake again, but this time my target was just one single bone. It worked, which is wierd.[image: Single Bone Bake]

Yet, baking all the bones one by one is not acceptable to me. So, what was I doing wrong? **How can I bake all the bone animation at once?**

Also, could it be a Blender Version problem? I used to use 3.0.1, but lately I switched to 3.2.2. I remember things uesed to work in 3.0.1, I never got this "nothing to bake" note before when I baked the pose bones animation.

FYI: [image] Here is the .blend file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried on v3.0.0, 3.2.2 and 3.3.0, I couldn't reproduce the issue.
Though, there is a confirmed bug on v3.2.2 that seems to be related to how selection tools fail to select the armature object when selecting bones. More about it there:
[⚓ T100879 Bake Action fails with "Nothing to Bake" if the Armature node isn't selected,](https://developer.blender.org/T100879)

Maybe try to first select everything with <kbd>A</kbd>, and if you see the armature is still not selected in the outliner: <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> a bone to make it active (which should make the armature selected again), and try baking again?

Comment: That is exactly what I came across, nice to know! Thank you L0Lock!!!

Comment: And yes, your method works. The Armature node was not selected untill I shift left click on one of the bones after I select every bone with A. I hope this bug gets fixed soon.